# Create WIC bitmap from managed array

Tags: bitmap, gdi+, wic

With GDI+ I can create a Bitmap backed by my own array like this:

```
// bitmap is int[]
GCHandle imageHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bitmap, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr imageDataPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bitmap, 0);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height, width * 4, Format32bppArgb, imageDataPtr);
```

Is it possible to do something similar with WIC bitmaps, to create a WIC bitmap from my own pre-allocated data? 
I could not find anything in the documentation, but maybe I'm missing something. For WIC I'm looking for a C++ solution, not C#.

Comment: Sure, for example with IWicBitmap::Lock: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690187.aspx

Comment: Lock gives access to bitmap data (which is useful if I cannot find another solution) but what I would like to do is something like this: hr = pFactory->CreateBitmap(width, height, formatGUID, WICBitmapCacheOnDemand, &myBitmapData, &pBitmap); - provide my pre-allocated data (myBitmapData) to CreateBitmap method.

Comment: No you can't do this but why would that be a problem?

Comment: I already have the image data in my application's structures and I did not want to duplicate it in WIC. But I guess I'll have to copy it between my structures and WIC.

Comment: I don't see how it changes anything between WIC and your sample. You always have to pass a pointer to scan0 (so force copy between your data and the underlying imaging technology).

Comment: The code above with GDI+ does not copy my data (from bitmap variable) to the allocated image. I allocate the image data (bitmap variable), pin it, and then use the pointer to pass it to Bitmap constructor. The image object will use my data as storage, it will not create its own storage.

Comment: How do you know GDI+ does not copy the bytes? If you change some bytes pointed by imageDataPtr will it be reflected automatically into the bitmap w/o any other action?

Comment: Yes, I can change the bytes and the changes are reflected automatically into the bitmap.

Comment: Check out [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) for example usage of WIC.